# How do I properly call an HTTPs callable function from my app?

Tags: typescript, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-functions

I followed some guides and wrote a cloud function. Now I need to call it from within my app. I did the following:

**Kotlin code:**

```
class ActivitySignup : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var functions: FirebaseFunctions
    private lateinit var user: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    functions = Firebase.functions
    ...
    submitbutton.setOnClickListener() {
            Log.e(tag,"Clicked submit")
            userEditTxt = findViewById(R.id.et_user)
            user = userEditTxt.text.toString().trim()

         auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.i(tag, "User created")

                    functions.getHttpsCallable("addUser")
                    .call(user)
                    .continueWith { task ->
                        // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
                        // has failed then result will throw an Exception which will be
                        // propagated down.
                        val result = task.result?.data as String
                        Log.e("result", result)
                        result
                    }

                    val intent = Intent(this, ActivityGroups::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()

                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(tag, "failure", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

        }

    }
```

**The cloud function in index.ts:**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log('addUser: ', data.username);

  const username = data.username
  functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
    const doc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc();
    return doc.set({
      createDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      modifiedDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), 
      username: username,
      email: user.email,    
      stat: 1, //0 = banned, 1 = normal
      uid: user.uid,
      rowpointer: doc.id,
    });
  });
```

However, there are 2 problems:

1. Android studio is highlighting the "functions" part of `Firebase.functions` in red. The error is `Unresolved reference: functions`
2. When I did `firebase serve` in Visual Studio, I got the following:

> - functions[addUser]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5000/APPNAME-cf4da/us-central1/addUser).
>
> i  functions: Beginning execution of "addUser"
>
> {"severity":"WARNING","message":"Request has invalid method. GET"}
>
> {"severity":"ERROR","message":"Invalid request, unable to process."}
>
> i  functions: Finished "addUser" in ~1s

I'm pretty new to Android dev/cloud functions, so I feel like I'm just making a rookie mistake somewhere...

Comment: I don't see any call to the Callable function in the Android code you shared. Calls look like the examples in the documenttion here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function Are you sure this is all that is needed to reproduce the error?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry about that! I added where the callable will be in the Kotlin code. And I've been told in the past that I put too much code in my questions...so I tried to put only the important things in my question. Anything else is standard to a Kotlin app?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that documentation you linked is exactly what I followed to get me to this point. It's this part that's giving me the problem: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#initialize_the_client_sdk

Comment: Thanks for the Android code that calls the Function. What is `.call(user)`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen from the docs, it's just `.call(data)`, which is any data that is relevant to the function. In my case, all I need is the username.

Comment: I understood that. But we need to see what you are passing in, and you're not showing how `user` is initialized.

Comment: Fixed! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This nesting makes no sense:

```
exports.addUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log('addUser: ', data.username);

  const username = data.username
  functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
    const doc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc();
    return doc.set({
      createDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      modifiedDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), 
      username: username,
      email: user.email,    
      stat: 1, //0 = banned, 1 = normal
      uid: user.uid,
      rowpointer: doc.id,
    });
  });
```

You seem to be trying to register a `functions.auth.user().onCreate` function inside a `functions.https.onCall` function, which is not possible. All Cloud Functions need to be top-level exports of your `index.js` file.

My best guess is that you want to pass information about the just created user from your Android code to the Cloud Function, in which case that should be in the `datsa` parameter that is passed to `onCall(data, context)`. If you actually "just" want to know the current user, you can also get that from `context.auth` as shown in documentation on [writing and deploying a callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function).

This is probably closer, although there may have been more problems in your original code:

```
exports.addUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log('addUser: ', data.username);
  const username = data.username;
  const email = data.email;
  const uid = context.auth.uid; //  get uid from context
  const doc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid); //  use uid as document ID
  return doc.set({
      createDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      modifiedDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), 
      username: username,
      email: email,    
      stat: 1, //0 = banned, 1 = normal
      uid: uid
  });
});
```

Comment: This is giving an error pointing to `context.auth.uid`. The error is `Object is possibly 'undefined'`.

Comment: That could indeed be, as I mostly focused on trying to show your an outline of what to do. 
 Treat this as pseudo-code showing you some key points of why your code doen't worjk. I recommend you search for more information about the error message, which is not Firebase-specific.