# How to send context parameter in unit test to a firebase functions running on the functions emulator

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools, chai-http

I manage to start the firebase emulators and load a cloud function. Now I want to write a test.

*PROBLEM* I use `chai-http` to call the function in the emulator but I do not succeed in sending a `context` to the function.

when calling the function using `chai-http`, I see the following warning and error :

`{"severity":"WARNING","message":"Request body has extra fields:  context"}`
`{"severity":"ERROR","message":"Invalid request, unable to process."}`

Here is the test code snippet :

```
    it("function_call", async() => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            chai.request(url)
                .post("")
                .send({
                    data: {
                        id: FILE_ID
                    },
                    context: {
                        auth: {
                            uid: USER_ID,
                            token: USER_TOKEN
                        }
                    }
                })
                .end(function(err, res) {
                    console.info(JSON.stringify(res));
                    const payload = JSON.parse(res.text);
                    chai.expect(payload.error).not.null;
                    resolve();
                });

        });
        // expect some data from firestore emulator to be deleted
        const afterCAll = await firestore.collection(`users/${USER_ID}/files/${FILE_ID}`).get();
        chai.expect(afterCAll.empty).is.true;
    });
```

And here is the function code :

```
export const doSomething = async(data, context) => {

    console.log("context=" + JSON.stringify(context));
    console.log("context.auth=" + JSON.stringify(context.auth));

}


export const CLOUD_FUNCTION = functions
    .runWith(runtimeOpts)
    .region("REGION")
    .https
    .onCall(doSomething);
```

And to execute the test, i run :

```
firebase emulators:exec --project dev-export 'npm test --prefix functions --verbose --debug'
```

Leaving out the context in the parameter :

```
            chai.request(url)
                .post("")
                .send({
                    data: {
                        id: FILE_ID
                    }
                })
```

and the function call to the emulator works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Looking for similar cases with the error you provided, I have a found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65997639/how-do-i-properly-call-an-https-callable-function-from-my-app) that tries to get user credentials from context, and I noticed the functions they were using were not asynchronous, you might want to check [`context`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https#oncall), and [`authData`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/common_providers_https.authdata) .
You can try:

```js
exports.doSomething = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const result = context;
    const result= context.auth;
    console.log("context=" + JSON.stringify(result));
    console.log("context.auth=" + JSON.stringify(resultAuth));
}
```